# TeraSort Algorithm using MPICH2 in C

Tags: c, algorithm, mpi, terasort

I am trying to implement TeraSort algorithm according to this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.04850.pdf) in C using MPICH2. Currently I am using small dataset with values given in the paper and using 4 processors.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

/********** Create and populate the array *********/
FILE *file = fopen("data.txt","r");
int n; //number of data values
fscanf(file,"%d",&n);
printf("%d",n);
int *original_array = malloc(n * sizeof(int));

int num,c;
int i=0;
while (fscanf(file, "%d", &num) == 1){
    original_array[i] = num;
    i++;
}
fclose(file);

/********* Finding max and min values ************/
int max = -32768;    //change if "int" is changed
int min = 32767;
for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    if(max < original_array[i]){
        max = original_array[i];
    }
    if(min > original_array[i]){
        min = original_array[i];
    }
}
printf("%d", min);
printf("\n");
printf("%d", max);
/********** Initialize MPI **********/

int world_rank;
int world_size;

MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

/********** FILE PLACEMENT **********/

int nodeDataSize = n/world_size;
printf("%d",nodeDataSize);
printf("\n");
MPI_Finalize();
```

All the values printed (n, min, max, nodeDataSize) are incorrect. The file data.txt contains space separated integers where the first integer gives the number of values. Can anyone tell me what's wrong?
This is what the data.txt file looks like: [image]

Comment: Test the return value of (most) functions with prototype in `<stdio.h>`. `fopen()... if (NULL) /* error */`; `if (scanf() != EXPECTED_ASSIGNMENTS) /* error */`; ...

Comment: How does your program fare for a single processor?

Comment: you can also post/link your data.txt

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] - this includes **minimal** necessary input data to reproduce the issue. Also elaborate what your own debugging issues have yielded so far.

Comment: @Evert The values are incorrect for single processor as well.

Comment: Please copy-paste the actual input file contents (as it's a simple text file): do not post (hard-to-read) images that contain the actual content.

Comment: For completeness, could you also show the compilation command (flags etc) you use for your example program?

Comment: As mentioned earlier, example output is also good to include in your question. And is the output the same each run, or does it vary?